# Making a simple 4 bit adder into a 4 bit adder with carry in & out

Tags: vhdl, adder

I have coded a simple signed 4 bit adder. It doesn't have any carry in or carry out so it easily overflows. 
Below you can see my code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity four_bit_adder_simple is
        port(
                A, B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                Sum : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end four_bit_adder_simple;

architecture signed_impl of four_bit_adder_simple is
begin
        sum <= std_logic_vector(signed(A) + signed(B));
end signed_impl;
```

Port mapping:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity four_bit_adder_tester is
    port(
            SW : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            LEDR : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end four_bit_adder_tester;

architecture tester_impl of four_bit_adder_tester is

begin

i1: entity work.four_bit_adder_simple(signed_impl)
    port map(
    A => SW(3 downto 0),
    B => SW(7 downto 4),
    Sum => LEDR(3 downto 0)
    );
end architecture;
```

How can I add a carry-in and a carry-out by using the resize function to change the bit size of the vectors before adding them together?

Comment: why do you have a requirement to use the resize function?

Comment: @BlairFonville
To prevent overflowing.

Comment: you prevent overflow by adding only 3 bit numbers

Comment: If your inputs and outputs are signed numbers, you can give them type `signed` instead of `std_logic_vector`. You then won't need any type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the resize function. Just create an internal signal of the correct length, and concatenate 0's to your inputs. Such as:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity four_bit_adder_simple is
    Port ( a    : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           b    : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           cin  : in  std_logic;
           sum  : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
           cout : out std_logic );
end four_bit_adder_simple;

architecture Behavioral of four_bit_adder_simple is
    signal total : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin

    total <= ('0'&a) + ('0'&b) + cin;
    sum   <= total(3 downto 0);
    cout  <= total(4);

end Behavioral;
```

*edit*

---

In hindsight, using the non-standard *std_logic_unsigned* is not the best approach ([When to use VHDL library std_logic_unsigned and numeric_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704135/when-to-use-vhdl-library-std-logic-unsigned-and-numeric-std)).

See my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/463608/111988) instead.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with the resize function? My assignment tells me to do so...

Comment: @user164324 I asked why you needed resize... you said "to prevent overflowing". But yes, you can replace the sum above with a sum of **signed(a)** and **signed(b)**, each resized to 5. Then cast that sum to std_logic_vector, and add cin. And put "use ieee.numeric_std.all" back.