# VHDL: Convert std_logic to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, typecast

I'm trying to make a 4 bit adder with carry in & out, but I am having trouble converting Cin (Carry-in) to the type std_logic_vector when summing Sum and Cin together below in the architecture. 
Do you have any idea how i can make these types fit so that I can perform arithmetic on them together?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity four_bit_adder_simple is
        port(
                A, B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                Cin : in std_logic;
                Sum : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
                Cout : out std_logic);
end four_bit_adder_simple;

architecture unsigned_impl of four_bit_adder_simple is
    signal total : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin
        Sum <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(A),5) + resize(unsigned(B),5));
        total <= Sum + Cin;
        Cout <= total(4);
end unsigned_impl;
```

**EDIT:** It was an error that I made Cout a 2 bit std_logic_vector. It should just have been a simple std_logic.

Comment: Cout is 2 bits wide, which is odd...  You are possibly missitg the fact that an array aggregate with one member can't use positional association. So use named association. (0 => Cin) is a 1 bit SLV.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You need to add Cin, not concatenate it. So the total line is wrong.

Comment: As @BrianDrummond says, Cout looks like it should be corrected to a std_logic output.

Comment: If Cout should be an SLV, it should be a 1 bit SLV, e.g. (0 downto 0). And I was merely converting Cin to a SLV. Who mentioned concatenation?

Comment: Re: your edit. You still have an error. Your output *Sum* doesn't take *Cin* into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `cin` to an unsigned, then add it in.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity four_bit_adder_simple is
    Port ( a    : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           b    : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           cin  : in  std_logic;
           sum  : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
           cout : out std_logic );
end four_bit_adder_simple;

architecture Behavioral of four_bit_adder_simple is
    signal total : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin

    total <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(a),5) + resize(unsigned(b),5) + unsigned'('0'&cin));
    sum   <= total(3 downto 0);
    cout  <= total(4);

end Behavioral;
```

You'll end up with this:
[image: adder]

Note that `resize` returns an unsigned here.

Comment: To simplify the code above, most type conversion/casting can be avoided by simply giving signals and ports the appropriate numeric type in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as to how the question was not actually answered:

```
signal s_vector: std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
signal s_bit   : std_logic : = '1';
...
s_vector <= (0 => s_bit);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simplification of your design that meets all the requirements and compiles in VHDL-93 onwards. It uses std_logic_unsigned rather than numeric_std. (Forgive the style changes, automatic when I typed and tested it.)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity FOUR_BIT_ADDER_SIMPLE is
  port(
    A                             : in  std_logic_vector( 3 downto  0);
    B                             : in  std_logic_vector( 3 downto  0);
    C_IN                          : in  std_logic;
    SUM                           : out std_logic_vector( 3 downto  0);
    C_OUT                         : out std_logic
  );
end FOUR_BIT_ADDER_SIMPLE;


architecture RTL of FOUR_BIT_ADDER_SIMPLE is

  signal total                    : std_logic_vector( 4 downto  0);

begin

  total  <=  ('0' & A) + ('0' & B) + ("0000" & C_IN);

  SUM    <=  total( 3 downto  0);
  C_OUT  <=  total( 4);

end architecture RTL;
```

The 5-bit addition is done in one line by first padding each element with leading zeroes.

Comment: You cannot add std_logic_vectors like that. You need to cast them to a numeric type first.

Comment: It doesn’t work. It is only supported in VHDL-2008, but you must use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.

Comment: @user110971 this does work but uses std_logic_unsigned, which is a non-standard package. You are correct that in VHDL-2008 the same functionality has been included in the standard library numeric_std_unsigned.

Comment: @ks0ze My above comment was a reply to a now deleted comment, so it seems confusing. Indeed the edited answer now works, but uses non-standard libraries, which is just bad practice. If you want to avoid excessive casting, you should just use Verilog. VHDL is a strongly typed language, which can be really annoying at times. In fact, I do prefer Verilog. See the original answer for the full context of my comment.

Comment: @ks0ze, I'm afraid the 'non-standard library' argument against std_logic_unsigned etc. is as antiquated as it is unrealistic and oft-repeated. That library has been distributed with practically all synthesis and simulation tools reliably for decades. I've used it in every project I've done for very many clients for decades and produced clear, concise, supportable and portable designs without the excessive casting others resort to. It's as valid as the 'so-called' standard libraries and isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @TonyM Well I know about a case wherein the change of an FPGA vendor almost resulted in someone’s death due to the use of non-standard libraries. Avoid good practice at your own peril.

Comment: @user110971, I think you need to re-examine the reality of the phrase 'non-standard' here. It's an oft-repeated fallacy that's easier to repeat than to assess realistically. As a supplier to large number of defence, avionics, marine, space and medical clients, I've had reliability and repeatability and successful code reviews. Quality of digital design and maintenance matter greatly to me and are examined as such.

Comment: Just a note: you don’t need to concatenation “0000” to *Cin*. The std_logic_unsigned library has a + operator overload to add std_logic to std_logic_vector.

Comment: @BlairFonville, that's very true but I value the explanatory nature of the long form, or whatever form that gives most clarity. Though trivial in this short file, engineers reading my files can see and understand the design more clearly.

Comment: @TonyM, I agree that every tool I have worked with supports std_logic_unsigned. I wouldn't think support would be dropped any time soon due to backwards comparability reasons, but now that the functionality has been rolled into the VHDL standard libraries I could see it happening at some point. Why support two implementations of the same library?

Comment: It's bad practice to perform arithmetic on `std_logic_vector` because the code lines and signals used to implement it give no clue as to whether the operation is supposed to be signed or unsigned. The whole point of a strongly typed language is to avoid this confusion and detect many classes of bug at compile time. Sure you *can* bypass some of this using `std_logic_unsigned`, but what if you want signed and unsigned arithmatic in the same file? If you find `numeric_std` results in excessive casting, you are not using the typing system effectively.

Comment: the nice thing about 2th complement arithmetic is, that the '+' operation doesn't care if the operands are signed or unsigned.